# What does Islam say about extramarital sex?

Tags: sex

**Types of sexual relationships,**

1. Sexual relationship between unmarried male and female.
2. Sexual relationship between a married male and an unmarried female.
3. Sexual relationship between an unmarried male and a married female.
4. Sexual relationship between married a male and a female who are not married themselves.

**I have two questions,**

1. What are the implications according to Islamic Law? (I need the precise ruling)
2. What are the implications on the day of judgment? (Add precise Quranic verses)

**P.S.**

Kindly, keep the body of the answer concise. If you add any reference, adding a hyperlink would be enough. Don't copy-paste Quranic verses.

Comment: All the types are haram, a married person would afront a harder punishment based on shari'a than a non-married. The 2nd question about judgment day can't be answred by us as we simply don't know. Also repentance might play a role on that.

Comment: I hope somebody can do that, I'm busy and therefore only commenting. But i recommend you to read the beginning of surat an-Nur 24.

Answer (score 3):

All sexual relations outside of marriage are forbidden ( [Quran 23:5-7](https://quran.com/23/5-7) ).

**Legal Punishments:**

For any of the given illicit relations, if the intercourse is proven by confession or four reliable witnesses:

- the married would be stoned to death (Hadith Saheeh Bukhari: [1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6820), [2](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6829) ; Hadith [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/29/34))
- the un-married  would be flogged with 100 stripes ( [Quran 24:2](https://quran.com/24/2) )

If one of them is married and the other unmarried, the above will apply to each individually: the married partner will be stoned and unmarried one will be flogged ( [Hadith Saheeh Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6835) )

**On Day of Judgement:**

Zina is a major sin and may be punished in the hereafter if repentance is not offered ( [Quran 25:68-70](https://quran.com/25/68-70) ). Allah may also forgive them if He wills or if they repent ( [Quran 4:48](https://quran.com/4/48) & [Quran 39:53](https://quran.com/39/53) & Hadith [Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/90) ).

Comment: What happens if an unmarried has sex multiple times?

Comment: The ruling remains the same. He will be flogged with 100 stripes every time he found guilt.